# pandas reorder only a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe file in which I want to switch the order of columns in only the third row while keeping other rows the same.

Under some condition, I have to switch orders for my project, but here is an example that probably has no real meaning.

Suppose the dataset is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df
```

out[1]:

```py
       A  B  C
    0  0  5  a
    1  1  6  b
    2  2  7  c
    3  3  8  d
    4  4  9  e
```

I want to have the output:

```py
       A  B  C
    0  0  5  a
    1  1  6  b
    2  **7  2**  c
    3  3  8  d
    4  4  9  e
```

How do I do it?

I have tried:

```py
    new_order =  [1,  0,  2] # specify new order of the third row
    i = 2 # specify row number
    df.iloc[i] = df[df.columns[new_order]].loc[i] # reorder the third row only and assign new values to df
```

I observed from the output of the right-hand side that the columns are reordering as I wanted:

```py
    df[df.columns[new_order]].loc[i]
Out[2]: 
B    7
A    2
C    c
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

But when assigned to df again, it did nothing. I guess it's because of the name matching.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.iloc[2] = df.iloc[2, new_order].values`?

Comment: That works well! Thank you!